# "type mismatch" while looping over a 2D array

Tags: rust

I can't get this code to compile:

```
fn main() {
  let grid: [[Option<i32>;2];2] = [
    [Some(1),Some(2)],
    [None,Some(4)],
  ];

  for row in grid.iter() {
    for v in row.iter() {
      match v {
        Some(x) => print!("{}", x),
        None => print!(" "),
      }
    }
    print!("\n");
  }
}
```

I get this error message

```
   Compiling array-2d v0.1.0 (file:///Users/paul/src/test/rust/array-2d)
src/main.rs:8:5: 13:6 error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, core::option::Option<i32>> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == core::option::Option<_>`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found enum `core::option::Option` [E0271]
src/main.rs: 8     for v in row.iter() {
src/main.rs: 9       match v {
src/main.rs:10         Some(x) => print!("{}", x),
src/main.rs:11         None => print!(" "),
src/main.rs:12       }
src/main.rs:13     }
src/main.rs:8:5: 13:6 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:7:3: 15:4 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:8:5: 13:6 help: run `rustc --explain E0271` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `array-2d`.
```

Can someone interpret that to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents. Additionally, the type annotation isn't needed, spaces come after commas, and you usually would see `for x in &collection`. [Example](http://is.gd/NnGUDw).

Comment: Can you explain why `for row in &grid` lets me leave off the `.iter()`?

Comment: Make sure you are familiar with [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book) sections on [iterators](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/iterators.html) and [loops](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/loops.html). The missing piece is that the `for` loop expression must adhere to [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which is automatically called. You'll note that `IntoIterator` is implemented for references to arrays and slices.

Comment: FWIW, I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30169) that clarifies that `IntoIterator` is used for `for` loops.

Comment: So you're saying a trait can be implemented for a reference to `T` but not for `T` itself? That is a new concept to me. Really?

Comment: *a trait can be implemented for a reference to `T` but not for `T` itself* — yup, they are different types.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You're just missing that `v` is a reference.

```
pub fn main() {
  let grid: [[Option<i32>;2];2] = [
    [Some(1),Some(2)],
    [None,Some(4)],
  ];

  for row in grid.iter() {
    for &v in row.iter() {
      match v {
        Some(x) => print!("{}", x),
        None => print!(" "),
      }
    }
    print!("\n");
  }

  // Keep in mind that i32 is Copy (but Option is not)
  // and an Array of X is Copy if X is Copy,
  // So there is no need to borrow v here, as follows:
  let grid2: [[i32;2];2] = [
    [1,2],
    [0,4],
  ];

  for row in grid2.iter() {
    for v in row.iter() {
      print!("{}", v);
    }
    print!("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So a follow-up question: I can't say `for row in grid` (no `.iter()`), but I *can* say `for &v in row`. Why is `.iter()` optional in the second line but not the first?

Comment: Because you can Copy an array rather than making a reference to it, as long as the contents of the array also implement Copy. i32 implements Copy, but Optional doesn't, so you can copy an [i32; 2] without any extra syntax but not an [Optional<i32>; 2].

Comment: I'm talking about the inner loop in the original code (with `Optional`). Why is `.iter()` required for the outer loop but not the inner loop? I think @Shepmaster answered it above by saying that `IntoIterator` is implemented by references to arrays but not arrays. Does that sound right?